# Determine function from values

Tags: functions, arithmetic

I have a function that works like this

```
f(x) = y
```

I can run it with whatever `x` I like, here are a couple of results

```
f(500) = 3.6
f(250) = 7.2
```

What I need to do is recreate the function but in order to do that I must first realize how it works. Obviously the input and output are inverse proportional and bound by a factor of 2 but I'm having a hard time describing that mathematically...

Comment: Well, $f(x)=\frac {1800}x$ works, but of course there are infinitely many functions that satisfy those two equations.  Without knowing more about the situation, it's not possible to say whether my example is the one you wanted.

Comment: What about graphing it first?

Comment: For instance, the linear function $f(x)=-.0144x+10.8$ also works.

Comment: @lulu that seems about as accurate as I needed it to be. Shame on me that I spent so much time and couldn't figure out something so simple...

Comment: I hope you have (many) other values to check!  Two values for a function really isn't very much information.

Comment: @lulu it's not really that important, I'm using a program to simulate a consumer on an electrical network where energy is measured (calculated) by impulses. The input is the interval between impulses and the output is the corresponding power. In my simulation I can set the interval but I wanted to program it so that I could set the required power instead and calculate the interval that I need to give to the program to simulate my configured power. This is exactly as I said, about as accurate as I needed :D

Comment: @lulu I even managed to figure out where that constant `1800` is coming from. It's due to my wattmeter's constant which is `2000` meaning that it sends 2000 impulses for every 1000 consumed watthours, the ratio of which is 2. Since energy is measured in watthours and I'm getting the power from the consumed energy I would need to divide by 3600, however my impulses/energy ratio is 2 thus 3600/2=1800. For another wattmeter the constant will be different. I'm feeling exceptionally smart today, or maybe I shouldn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without telling us more about the function, it is impossible to answer your question. There are infinitely many functions which satisfy the conditions $f(500)=3.6$ and $f(250)=7.2$.

For example, one of them would be

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}7.2 & \text{if }x=250\\
3.6&\text{if } x=500\\
\pi& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

There is nothing about your question that we can use to conclude that the above function *isn't* what we are looking for, but also nothing to conclude that it *is*.

Comment: Thankfully I didn't need an absolutely definite mathematical answer so what lulu suggested in the comments `f(x)=1800/x` worked for me, however I suppose this is the correct answer to the question, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: @php_nub_qq So you were looking for a function that graphs to a fairly smooth line or curve. On the one hand you should have said that, but on the other hand I would have thought it a reasonable assumption.